# The best way to store "Item-ItemDetails" in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, nsmanagedobjectmodel

As 99% of iOS apps, mine has a main screen with a long list of items, and when a user taps one, he sees item details. Pretty much straightforward. Let's say, to render the first screen I need **titles** and **images**. And for the second one - **a large html**. All the data is stored persistently in `CoreData`.

I want the list (`UICollectionView`) to be as fast as possible. So I can't load html-s until a user is on the details screen.

How can it be implemented? Should I create two `NSManagedObject` classes: `Item` and `ItemDetails`? Does `CoreData` load everything lazily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting it into `Item` and `ItemDetails` is a good approach.

I'd check first, though, if it's really a performance problem. You want to be sure to understand how setting a batch size affects fetch performance. The *Accessing Data* and *Performance* chapters in our [Core Data book](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/) goes into all the details.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'm really going to buy this book. But, in short, is there a way to be always on a safe side? Even if one day I had an item with 1 Mb html.

Comment: Yes, if the data is big, using `Item` and `ItemDetails` with a one-to-one relationship is the best approach.